# Return only nested field from query in ElasticSearch Spring project

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the following POJOs

```
@Document(indexName = "person", type = "user")
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<Car> car;

// getter/setter

}
```

```
public class Car {

    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String model;

// getter/setter
}
```

And in the class below I want to retrieve the nested field "cars" directly for a given Person with the name passed as parameter but it returns a List with null value.

```
public class ElasticsearchRepo {

    private ElasticsearchOperations op;

    public List<Car> getCars(String name) {
        String[] includeFields = new String[]{"car"};
        String[] excludeFields = null;

        NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", name))
            .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(includeFields, excludeFields)).build();

        SearchHits<Car> searchHits = op.search(query, Car.class, IndexCoordinates.of("person"));

        return customerSearchHits.getSearchHits().stream().map(s -> s.getContent().getCars())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

However, if in the searchHits code above I change the class to Person as shown below, I will get returned the pojo Person where the property "cars" is the only one filled in (all other properties are retrieved as null):

```
 SearchHits<Person> searchHits = op
            .search(query, Person.class, IndexCoordinates.of("person"));
```

But how may I retrieve directly the nested property cars?

Answer (score 1):

When querying the *person* index, Elasticsearch will return Person documents - with only the fields that you defined in the sourcefilter. And Spring Data Elasticsearch maps these documents to the given entity. But it cannot map a source docuument with a *car* property toa class having *name* and *model* properties. That's why in your first case the returned persons are mapped to empty objects.

The second way you have is the correct one: retrieve the persons and extract the cars from these objects.

If you like to do it with streams:

```java
List<Car> cars = operations.search(query, Person.class, IndexCoordinates.of("person"))
    .stream().map(SearchHit::getContent)
    .flatMap(person -> person.getCar().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, so in ElasticSearchRepositories there is no way we can use projection like we may use in JPARepositories for example where we can make a query and return a spefic property of an entity represented by a pojo?

Comment: 1. Spring Data Elasticsearch does not support projections. 2. The projections in Spring Data JPA or for example Spring Data MongoDB project attributes of the root entity (Person) - that would be for example a `CarOnly` entity that has a `List<Car> car` property. You want to project onto a class that has different properties than the root entity.